# How to validate the output of "Execute a SQL query" action in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have created an Azure Logic App by adding **Execute a SQL query (V2)** action. In the Execute a SQL query action, I have used the following query to get the specific column data.

> select XXXX from [dbo].[XXXX] where XXXX=@{triggerBody()?['XXXX']?['XXXX']}

I’m getting the column data by using the following expression:

> body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][0][<'Name of table column'>]

But for some scenarios **Execute a SQL query** action returns the following response:

```
{
  "ResultSets": {},
  "OutputParameters": {}
}
```

Whenever **Execute a SQL query** action returns empty response, then I'm getting the following error:

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Set_variable' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'int(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][0]['XXXX'])' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected

So, can anyone suggest me how to validate the “**ResultSets**” object is null or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below **expression** and **conditions** to evaluate if the `ResultSets` are `empty` and then proceed with further steps.

```
equals(string(outputs('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['body']['ResultSets']),'{}')
```

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

If its `true`, that means it empty set.

Comment: Cheers! I used "true" as a string and not as a function like in your image. Fixed it for me!